# How do I dynamically create multiple PictureBox instances from images in folder?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create pictures boxes dynamically from a folder containing images, but in my code I can only create one picture box. How do I do to create one picture box per image?

Here is my code:

```
 namespace LoadImagesFromFolder
 {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures", "*.jpg");
        foreach (string image in images)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(image); 

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: All `Bitmap`s created are assigned to the same `pictureBox1`, is this intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a dialog to select the files, create the `PictureBox` controls dynamically in the `foreach` loop and add them to the form's (or other container control's) `Controls` collection.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog d = new OpenFileDialog();

    // allow multiple selection
    d.Multiselect = true;

    // filter the desired file types
    d.Filter = "JPG |*.jpg|PNG|*.png|BMP|*.bmp";

    // show the dialog and check if the selection was made
    if (d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (string image in d.FileNames)
        {
            // create a new control
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

            // assign the image
            pb.Image = new Bitmap(image);

            // stretch the image
            pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

            // set the size of the picture box
            pb.Height = pb.Image.Height/10;
            pb.Width = pb.Image.Width/10;

            // add the control to the container
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the accepted answer because this answer is most complet, has the dialog. Thx all

Comment: @illDev, maybe you should specify your needs in the question next time. A selective dialog and an automatic list of images are two completely different things. Your question is quite specific and I answered all of your questions. Your call tho, happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You're just rewriting the image value for your single PictureBox (`pictureBox1`), but you need to create a new PictureBox for every picture instead and set its value. Do that and you'll be fine.

Something like this (just an example, modify this to your needs!)

```
foreach (string image in images)
{
   PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();
   picture.Image = new Bitmap(image); 
   someParentControl.Controls.Add(picture);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with someParentControl?

Comment: @illDev that would be something like a `FlowLayoutPanel`

Comment: @illDev, the control where you want to place your pictureboxes in. We usually call these wrappers "Parent controls" and they contain "Children" inside. You need to modify `someParentControl` to the control ID you need. That may be some kind of a `Panel` for instance.